# Swipe between apps but continue to see the menu bar

Tags: macos, fullscreen

What I really like about my Magic Mouse is that I can swipe between apps using two finger swipes.

But it only works for apps that are in full screen. That is okay, but I miss the menu bar when those apps are in full screen. I use full screen a lot, but purely because I want the swiping. I even miss the dock sometimes.

Can I have swiping and the menu bar at the same time?

Note that I have OS X 10.10.1.

Answer (score 1):

Try placing applications in "maximized mode" in their own seperate desktop. Do this by `OPT+Click`ing the green button to make the window maximized (or resize the window), then drag the window, pushing it against the top of the screen. This will trigger Mission Control. Still holding the window, drag it to the "new desktop" icon in the upper-right corner to place the window in it's own desktop.

Screen recording of this: https://youtu.be/8QI-UkKmMPw

It may be slow to set up, but you'll still be able to use the two-finger swipe to move between applications, while still having the menu bar and dock.

To close desktops (which moves windows from that desktop into the next available desktop), enter Mission Control (`F3`), move the cursor to the top of the window, and hover your cursor over the desktop. A close icon should appear in the upper-left corner of the icon.

Hopefully this will be helpful.

Comment: Hey, this was very helpful to me, but there were some small differences. 

Firstly, I had to OPT+Shift+Click the green button to maximise the window.

Secondly, dragging the window up into the menu bar as demonstrated in your video did not work on my system. (Don't know why, do you have another version of OS X?) So basically, I just maximised all my apps, then went to mission control by double tapping the mouse with two fingers, and then dragged all my apps onto separate desktops. Now it works perfectly, I even have my dock visible like I do prefer.

Comment: I'm still looking for ways to achieve this in a more speedy way that takes less work. Therefore I will keep this question open for a few days. If there is no other way to do it, I will accept your answer.

Comment: I have OSX 10.11.2; after doing [some research](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204100) it seems the dragging-into Mission Control feature was added in OSX El Capitan.